# Kivy: python-for-android, how to see contents of public.mp3

Tags: android, ubuntu, mp3, apk, kivy

I packaged an apk using python-for-android but the file size is 108mb and 102mb of which belonged to public.mp3. How do I find out what is inside public.mp3? Google has an apk limit of 50mb so I need to know why my package is so large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tar file, so extract it with `tar xf` or similar.